# Solving $f(z) = f( z-z^2)$ for $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, induction, taylor-expansion, functional-equations

This is a question that I came across in a math competition and I solved it the following way. But unfortunately, I received 0 out of 20. Are there any errors in my reasoning?

> $f: \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ and $f$ is analytic everywhere in the complex plane. $\forall z \in C$ we have $f(z)= f\left(z-z^2\right)$. Prove that $f(z)$ has to be a constant in the entire plane.

---

**My approach:**
Since $f$ is analytic everywhere, therefore its Taylor series expansion about $z=0$ has to be convergent $\forall z\in C$. Therefore we have:
$$
\begin{split}
f(z)     &= f(0) + f'(0) z + \frac{f''(0)}{2} z^2 + \ldots \\
f(z-z^2) &= f(0) + f'(0)(z-z^2) + \frac{f''(0)}{2} (z-z^2)^2 + \ldots
\end{split}
$$

So the two series are equal for all complex inputs, therefore the coefficients of the same powers of $z$ have to be equal. So I went on calculating the coefficient of $z^2$ in the second series and concluded that $\frac{f''(0)}{2} = - f'(0) + \frac{f''(0)}{2}$. So $f'(0)=0$. I decided to prove by induction that $\forall n \in N, f^n(0)=0$ and therefore, the proof will be complete.

Suppose that $f'(0) = f''(0) = ... = f^n(0)=0$. If we can prove that $f^{n+1}(0)=0$, the induction will be complete. By the hypothesis of the induction we have:
$$
f(z) = f(0) + \frac{f^{n+1}(0)}{(n+1)!}z^{n+1}
     + \frac{f^{n+2}(0)}{(n+2)!}z^{n+2} + \ldots 
$$
and therefore,
$$
f(z-z^2) = f(0) + \frac{f^{n+1}(0)}{(n+1)!}(z-z^2)^{n+1}
         + \frac{f^{n+2}(0)}{(n+2)!}(z-z^2)^{n+2} + \ldots
$$

By using the Newton's binomial formula I calculated the coefficients of $ z^{n+1}$ and $z^{n+2}$ and concluded that $ \frac{f^{n+2}(0)}{(n+2)!} = \frac{f^{n+2}(0)}{(n+2)!}- (n+1)\frac{f^{n+1}(0)}{(n+1)!}$ and finally $f^{n+1}(0) = 0$
Therefore, $f(z) = f(0)  \  \forall z \in C$.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: I don't see how you got $0$... this solution seems correct.

Comment: You incorrectly dropped the constant term in your induction step, but that shouldn’t affect the proof. I think it’s not obviously true that can split up/rearrange terms and get the same convergent series. I think it still works, but you’d need to be careful.

Comment: Probably any solution deviating from the approved one costs 0.

Comment: @Eric The base case was $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: @user you'd still need to have "$f(z) = f(0) + \frac{f^{n+1}(0)}{(n+1)!}(z-z^2)^{n+1}
         + \frac{f^{n+2}(0)}{(n+2)!}(z-z^2)^{n+2} + \ldots$" and such, that's what Eric pointed out.

Comment: @eric you're write I forgot f(0) here but I did write it in the exam. and What I did with f(z-z^2) is allowed by a theorem called the substitution theorem for power series. I found it in mathematical analysis by Tom Apostol. theorem 9.16

Comment: In any case, as presented here (and with $f(0)$s at the correct places), I don't really see any issue with your proof Aria. What competition was it by the way? Just to make sure it's not still active or anything.

Comment: @BrunoB you're totally right. I dropped f(0) in my post and I don't know how to edit it. Apparently I can't. 
It's Iran's math competition which is held annually. Apparently they only give points to the solutions that they have in mind :)

Comment: There should be an Edit option at the bottom left of your post, among other options like Share or Cite. Also, I'll politely say that this kind of notation system is really dumb, creativity is at the heart of maths...

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks. I fixed the mistake.

Comment: $f(1/2)=f(1/4)=f(3/16)=...=f(0)$. But, constant values of analytic functions are isolated.  Contradiction. Is this solution correct?

Comment: @BobDobbs great approach! thank you.

Comment: The identity theorem works as well with the set of values that Bob Dobbs indicates.

Comment: Changed tag to [tag:solution-verification], since the primary question seems to be that the proposed solution was not marked properly.

Comment: There is no problem with the rearanging term of the series since the function $f$ is entire in particular the power series converge absolutely everywhere, and I don't see any problem with your approach, but I prefere the one given by Bob Dobbs ($f$ is constant on a converging sequence $(U_n)_n$)  which is more quick and don't need that $f$ is analytic in the whole complex plan.

Comment: I like the sequence argument though the result can also be seen in terms of degree...  The relation is preserved under translation so you may as well assume $f(0)=0$. With $p(z)=z-z^2$: if $f$ is non-constant pick a simple $\gamma$ that generates a [counter-clockwise] circle of radius $r\gt 2$ on which $f$ is non-zero and by application of the Argument Principle $0\lt k= n\big(f\circ \gamma,0\big) = n\big(f\circ p\circ\gamma,0\big)\geq 2 k$ [impossible] since for $w \in B\big(0,r\big)$ we have $n\big(\gamma, w\big)=1$ but $n\big(p\circ \gamma, w\big)=2$ per Rouche.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach looks sound and is in addition to the *[Identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)* mentioned in the comment section a nice and instructive solution.

Comment: Thank you for your correction!

Comment: @Aria: You're welcome.